# Keyboard doesnt get active on onfocus( ) in Android PhoneGap

Tags: cordova

I am working on one PhoneGap app with cordova version 2.9.0. Now the issue which I am facing is, when I put the $("#text_demo").focus() on document ready function/ init method, then I get the cursor on the text field. But I also want the keyboard to get open up on focus() method.
I tried many solutions, but not working, Can anybody please help me out?

Comment: Opening the keyboard by setting the focus to an input element, will only work if the focus is set within a "user context" (e.g. click, mousedown, mouseup).

Answer (score 0):

`Opening the keyboard` by setting the `focus to an input element`, will only work if the focus is set within a `"user context"` (e.g. click, mousedown, mouseup).

Try like this

```
$(document).on("click","#button", function(){
$("#fc").focus();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I once had the same desire to streamline the user experience but after doing a survey of published apps on both IOS and Android, I have only seen the tap focus open the keyboard. So your requirement to open the keyboard automatically is highly non-standard and will probably confuse users rather than help them.

That said - I came across this recipe/API for opening and closing the keyboard on Android.

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/How-to-show-and-hide-soft-keyboard-in-Android

Excerpt below:

```
     public void showKeyBoard() {
           InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) mGap.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
           // only will trigger it if no physical keyboard is open
           mgr.showSoftInput(mAppView, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);

           ((InputMethodManager) mGap.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).showSoftInput(mAppView, 0);

    }

    public void hideKeyBoard() {
        InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) mGap.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mAppView.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
```